# recreated Search Svc App twice but still getting unable to retrieve topology components

Tags: 2013, search

I recreated Search Svc App twice but still getting "Unable to retrieve topology component health states. This may be because the admin component is not up and running."

administrative status = running

search services are running with the correct search service account

```
$AppServer = "SRVSHA13DEV01"
$SearchServer = "SRVSHA13DEV01"
$SearchAppPoolName = "SharePoint Service Applications"
$SearchServiceName = "Search Service Application"
$SearchServiceProxyName = "Search Service Application Proxy"
$DatabaseName = "SP2013_DEV_Search_AdminDB"

#Get Service Application Pool
$spAppPool = Get-SPServiceApplicationPool -Identity $SearchAppPoolName

#Start Search Service Instance on all Application Servers
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance $AppServer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance $SearchServer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceInstance $AppServer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceInstance $SearchServer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Create Search Service Application
$ServiceApplication = New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Partitioned -Name $SearchServiceName -ApplicationPool $spAppPool.Name -DatabaseName $DatabaseName

#Create Search Service Proxy
New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplicationProxy -Partitioned -Name $SearchServiceProxyName -SearchApplication $ServiceApplication
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your farm's search topology as it regards servers?

Comment: Show us the PowerShell you are using to create the Search Service app. Have you confirmed the Databases are getting created? Are you certain that you do not have virus scanning running on the Search Application directories?

Comment: It's a single server for DEV. Powershell is added now with the original post. the virus scan is admin by another team. what directory needs to be added for exclusion? I verified all the databases are created.

Comment: I found the location to be excluded from scan  C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. Even Microsoft could not solve the issue (as of this point). A service application "Search Administration Web Service for Search Service Application" is also created when "search service application" is provisioned. I don't know why but I had to grant permission for service_spfarm account manually. walla, everything started to work like a charm.